# Get ID for each array element inside second array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to get unique ID for each array element inside second array. That ID already exist in table but I cant get them separately. URL that am getting now looks like this: http://page.com/index.php?p=view&m=area&id=173id=552id=768id=36id=217id=
I need just one ID and if first is used set second and so on.
I know that I should use mysqli or PDO and normalized tables but that later, now I need help with this.

This is the code:

```
$res= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM area WHERE user='$user' ORDER BY date") or     die("Error: " . mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
   $id = $row['id'];
   $x = array();
   $parent = array();
   foreach($row as $value)
   {
      if ($value == $id) continue;

      else if ($value == $user) continue;

      $result = explode(",", $value);

      foreach($result as $newvalue)
      {
         $query = "SELECT x,firm FROM list where list.x='$newvalue'";
         $result = mysql_query($query);
         $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
         $x[] = $r['x'];
         $xx = implode("id=",$x);
         $parent[] = $r['firm'];
         $list = implode("<a href='index.php?p=view&m=area&$xx'>", $parent)."</a>";
      }
    }
echo "<td><span>" . $list . "</span>/td>";

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

first of all

```
$list = implode("<a h
```

should be

```
$list .= implode("<a h
```

Comment: that exactly what you are doing - you are adding to $parent for every row you get from database - so maybe you also want to "$parent = array();" in the beginning of foreach and not before

Answer (score 0):

That URL syntax is not the correct way to pass an array of values to a PHP script. It should use PHP array syntax for the parameter names. Also, you need separate your parameters with an ampersand (`&`):

```
 http://page.com/index.php?p=view&m=area&id[]=173&id[]=552&id[]=76&8id[]=36&id[]=217
```

Then you can get the second one by using

```
$second_id = $_GET['id'][1]; // 552
```

etc.

FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: i dont need second id. just first. rest need to be deleted, hidden or whatever

Comment: we are thinking about different pages. i know how to get it but first i need to show it correctly. now it is: &id=173id=552id=768 but should be: http://page.com/index.php?p=view&m=area&id=173 and http://page.com/index.php?p=view&m=area&id=552 and so on. its multiple links on same page